# iOS - use Aceess database and sharepoint to push and pull data

Tags: ios, swift, ms-access, sharepoint

Currently I am creating app that needs to store and pull data from database by multiple users.
Since I do not have much knowledge in database, MS Access, and MS Sharepoint, I would like to know if it is possible to use share point as database for my iOS application, which implemented in pure swift code.

Any one with knowledge in this field please help me by providing advice on if it works, and, if possible, how can I successfully implement this.

Thank you for all the helps.

Comment: What kind of data would you be pulling back? I've used SharePoint to host data (Strings and images) before.

Comment: @Daniel: I would like to store and pull string data. I have all the licenses to MS. How did you achieve put/pull of string/img data with share point. I really like to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t see why this would not work. As long as the SharePoint tables follow the rules for Access, then you can place the ms-access application on each desktop. Anytime “any” user of that application updates or adds records, then all other users will “eventually” see the updates. So in this setup, the desktop users can in fact “run” the application “off line”. The instant such users get Wi-Fi or a connection (or always have one), then the data is synced in real time.

The above setup takes no coding and is part of the Access system which supports those SharePoint tables.

As for the iOS and that part of the application? Again, I see little problem since all of the abilities of SharePoint are available as a web service. So as long as your development platform supports standard web services, then your application can interact with that web service to retrieve and update rows of data in those SharePoint tables. As noted, the “sync” to the Access clients will thus reflect any updates to that data.

Since near every modern phone development system supports interaction with web services, then the phone software can do the same. You not have an ODBC like interface, but you can query the data (CAMEL).

The Access desktop client will also be interacting with the SharePoint tables via a web service, but from Access point of view the SharePoint tables (lists) look like any regular SQL like table. So standard VBA code and DAO reocrdsets are supported.

The web services for SharePoint are outlined here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479390(v=office.12).aspx

And this video shows how you can upload data to SharePoint from Access, and NOTE how the relational table ability of SharePoint is supported by Access. Once that data is uploaded, then Access supports updating of such data as if the data was a local table.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wdjYIby_b0&list=PL27E956A1537FE1C5&index=2

You can use a single office 365 account at $6 per month for the above, and that single account supports 500 free users. So if you don’t have SharePoint (or don’t want to bother with SharePoint, a single office 365 account also offers these SharePoint services for that one stupid low price of $6 per month – and that account with work with the free Access runtime that that you can use to run the Access side for free on the desktop part of this application.

Comment: Thank you very much for all these information. After some research, I figured out sharepoint has REST APIs so rather than using MS-Access. I decided to use just sharepoint with simple table. Also thank you for kindly posting all these information. Very appreciated.